# Put env variable into frontend js file during runtime using docker-compose / docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, frontend, runtime

I'm a novice at using docker and am currently trying to set a backend URL dynamically within a frontend .js file during **runtime**. I have an application which consists of a frontend and a backend. As of now, the backend URL can be specified in the docker-compose.yml as follows:

```
myFrontend:
build:
  context: ./frontend-dockerfile-location
  args:
    BACKEND_URL: myBackendUrl
```

In the corresponding dockerfile I create an nginx base, copy all my static files over there and then set the correct backend URL.

```
FROM nginx:latest
#access the arg defined in the yml file
ARG myBackendUrl
#write the backend url into the containers environment
ENV myBackendUrl=${myBackendUrl}
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/
#replace the config.js URL placeholder with the environment variable
RUN envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js.tmp && mv      /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js.tmp /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js
```

The problem with this setup is that I would always have to build the image anew whenever I wish to change the backend URL. That's when I started to look for possible solutions how I could change my backend URL during runtime. And this is where my first question arises. Is it even possible to change env variables during runtime or does runtime refer to "setting env variables when you start your container"?

My second question regards possible solutions that I have come across. First I was wondering if a suitable solution for my problem would be webpack. Since my frontend will be served to a client and run on their browser, I can not simply define env variables and access them via process.env; I do not have a working solution yet, but I believe that this might be the answer to my question. Another alternative which I think could work is the entrypoint instruction. I read that this allows the definition of a starup command and was wondering if I could just put my shell script syntax that I am currently using in the dockerfile into a shell script and make this the entrypoint of my image. If I understand this correctly, it would always run my script when starting a container, thus allowing me to change the URL without having to rebuild the image.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with these questions because I am having a hard time wrapping my head around some of these concepts, even after reading about them multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the same trick as yours, using a sed command to replace placeholder in Javascript. I am pretty sure, there is a better way to do this. However about your issue, you can use your script to replace the placeholder, it has to execute with CMD or ENTRYPOINT command chained with your NGINX command, the URL is passed by env not using build arguments.

```
....
#remove ARG + ENV with no value or default
ENV myBackendUrl
...
CMD envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js.tmp && mv /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js.tmp /usr/share/nginx/html/js/config.js && nginx -g daemon off
```

On the command line:

```
docker-compose --env-file <env_file> up 
docker-compose -e myBackendUrl=<url> up
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. In regards to the real-time aspect, I went with server-side rendering using express.js and ejs. Might be interesting for someone who runs into a similar issue.